# monitor pipe in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin

I have multiple pipe bash command, but let's simplify it to this command:

```
echo "12 JAN 2023" | date -d -
```

the output is:

```
So 10. června 2023, 00:00:00 CEST
```

I want to monitor, what is going through the pipe, so I want the output to stdout:

```
12 JAN 2023
So 10. června 2023, 00:00:00 CEST
```

So I look for a program:

```
echo "12 JAN 2023" | pipemonitor | date -d -
```

Only thing I have:

```
echo "12 JAN 2023" |\
cat > /dev/shm/pipemonitor.tmp; cat /dev/shm/pipemonitor.tmp; cat /dev/shm/pipemonitor.tmp |\
date -d -
```

This has the output:

```
12 JAN 2023
So 10. června 2023, 00:00:00 CEST
```

but it is a bit clumsy.

So I write pipes with backslases now and insert this line in between, when I need to monitor the pipe.

```
command1 |\
command2 |\
cat > /dev/shm/pipemonitor.tmp; cat /dev/shm/pipemonitor.tmp; cat /dev/shm/pipemonitor.tmp |\
command3 |\
command4
```

Can you thing about something simpler? An output of the pipemonitor might be even to stderr. Even pv did not worked.

Thanks.

Comment: I see that the example of date is not good as echo "12 May 2023" | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8  date -d - does output Sat Jun 10 12:00:00 AM CEST 2023... Strange, may be a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard output of a command in the middle of a pipeline is connected to the standard input of the next command; what you want is something that prints to the controlling terminal *and* standard output. Easily done with [`tee`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html):

```bash
$ echo "12 JAN 2023" | tee /dev/tty | date -d -
12 JAN 2023
Fri Jun  9 12:00:00 AM PDT 2023
```

(Not suitable for use in a non-interactive environment)

Comment: Why `Not suitable for use in a non-interactive environment` ? If you put the line in a script file and run it, that will output the same, right ?

Comment: @Philippe If there's no controlling terminal, /dev/tty isn't going to work. If you want it to work without that (e.g. in a cron job, or even just an ssh session where you didn't use `ssh -t` to allocate a pseudo-terminal), you'd have to do something more complicated like `{ echo "12 JAN 2023" | tee /dev/fd/3 | date -d -; } 3>&1`

Comment: @GordonDavisson A `typical`  non-interactive environment is just a script running normally without redirection (in which case /dev/tty should work), not a cron job or ssh without `-t`.

Comment: @Philippe "Non-interactive" may not be the best term; the critical thing is whether there's a controlling terminal, not whether bash is running with the `-i` flag.

Comment: Great! You are a smart boy (I suppose)! :-) That is what I was looking for. Thanks.